# Angular router how to cast window.history.state to a class when retrieve state object

Tags: angular

I am suing the following code example to pass object to route using state

```
@Component({
  template: `<a (click)="navigateWithState()">Go</a>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(public router: Router) {}
  navigateWithState() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/123', { state: { hello: 'world' } });
  }
}
```

While reading the state, i would like to cast this to a the class object. How to cast this to a class object?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details-page',
  template: '<pre>{{ state$ | async | json }}</pre>'
})
export class DetailsPageComponent implements OnInit {
  state$: Observable<MyClass>;

  constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.state$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap
      .pipe(map(() => (window.history.state) as MyClass))
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a new instance of MyClass using window.history.state as constructor parameters?

Comment: Basically i just need few properties from windoe history state and not all.